# Modify vertices in a THREE.BufferGeometry object

Tags: three.js

I need to selectively show/hide 1000+ lines of different sizes, positions and colors.

My first attempt made a THREE.Geometry with a name for each. To hide/show I iterate over scene and hide/show on each based on name and my heuristic. That seemed very slow - around 50Hz for ~1000 lines.

I made a test using a similar approach but using only a single THREE.Geometry to hold all of the lines. That was much faster but of course but I can only apply one material to all the lines which is no good. I was able to set the right flags and update the positions of the lines while the app was running though.

The best approach seems to be to use THREE.BufferGeometry. I made a test which was very fast and worked as expected for the initial set up but I was unable to change the position/visibility and color of each line afterwards. I made a JS fiddle that illustrates it - http://jsfiddle.net/SSnKk/ - but calling `buffer_geometry.dynamic = true;` and `buffer_geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` didn't appear to help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you update the contents of the attribute buffers, you need to set the `needsUpdate` flag. For example:

```js
buffer_geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

buffer_geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
```

three.js r.143

Comment: Following on from that - I'd like to have the lines start away from the origin. When I change the start location, I don't see what I'd expect. Is it possible to use buffer geometry with a set of lines at arbitrary positions?  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9nVqU/

Comment: Please make a new post with your new question.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867293/creating-three-lines-with-different-endpoints-using-three-buffergeometry

Comment: The API had changed slightly since the above. This modified fiddle works at the time of writing: http://jsfiddle.net/hjx3rLmt/1/

Comment: @AndrewE Thanks. Updated answer.