# optimise three.js face3 rendering for loads of polygons

Tags: javascript, optimization, three.js, polygons

I have an large array (50,000 to 100,000 elements) with each element containing another array of 3 points that define the vertices of a polygon. Some vertices have a parameter addition built in to the array, e.g;

```
var array = [
[[967.6719, 657.401, -1008.1],[967.6719, 657.401, -1001.1],[967.1551, 657.4806, -1008.1]],
[[967.1551, 657.4806, -1008.1 + LENGTH],[967.6719, 657.401, -1001.1],[967.1551, 657.4806, -1001.1]],
...etc
];
```

The length parameter is controlled by a slider bar. Currently the initial load time is way too long and any changes to the parameter also takes ages to update. Is there a way to optimise this?

I am currently rendering the polygons with this code;

```
function drawShapes(array) {

    scene.remove( all_shapes );
    all_shapes = new THREE.Object3D();
    var LENGTH = inpLength.valueAsNumber; 
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x02B700, linewidth: 2 } );
    var triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry(); 

    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (var n=0; n<3; n++){
          triangleGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( array[i][n][0], array[i][n][1], array[i][n][2]));

        }

        triangleGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
        triangleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, material); 
        all_shapes.add(triangleMesh)
        var triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry(); 
    }

    scene.add( all_shapes );

}
```

Comment: You could try using an unindexed `BufferGeometry` instead, that might speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: You could also only update the existing geometry when changing your `length` using the input from the slider. Why redraw the whole thing? Changing those vertices should not be a problem in this case.

Comment: do you mean something like this?https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_dynamic.html

Comment: Yes, or even better with using `THREE.BufferGeometry`; an example can be found **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16805021/1697459)**

Comment: > var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x02B700, linewidth: 2 } );

Should be

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x02B700 } );